# Need Account fields to lookup existing names on entry

Tags: lookup, validation

I am part of a committee working on a SalesForce design plan for a non-profit. It is likely that data entry will be done by volunteers around the US, and there may be little local control over the process. So, as much as possible we need to set rules and validation on the fields.

At this time, the Account field in Donations is a textbox that allows entry. Next to it is a lookup field, but the lookup is not forced. Is it possible to set the field to automatically do a lookup, based on what the user enters?

Comment: Hi Nora. Please provide additional commentary about 1) SF edition, 2) Classic or LEX.

Comment: How would I find that? All I know is that it's the Non-profit Starter Pack. I have quite a bit of database and UX design experience, but not much SalesForce experience specifically.

Comment: perfect. You've answered 1), please provide screenshot of the SF screen you are asking about... that should answer question 2) "Classic or LEX".

Comment: Hmmm, I have never added a screenshot in StackExchange. Will this work [link](https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/19144047_10158783341430654_3354516045204941224_o.jpg?oh=bfe85c756c8c19ccd031e9a3778c03cb&oe=59E76E2E)

Comment: yep that worked. thanks. ok, that is "classic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Account Name" field is a lookup field. It is also a required field on this page layout (your screenshot).

It is true that a User can type anything they want into the lookup field and click "Save" (without first clicking the lookup icon and linking the donation record to an Account), but SF will definitely enforce the fact that this is a lookup field. This is not a free-form field where anything goes!

Consider...

Case 1: user enters a valid Account Name for an existing Account. No typos. Also, for this case assume there is only one Account with this name. Clicking Save (without first engaging with lookup magnifying glass button) will associate the donation record just fine with that Account, even though the lookup button was not engaged with.

Case 2: user enters an Account Name for an Account that does not yet exist... or typo. Clicking Save (without first engaging with lookup magnifying glass button) will not associate the donation record with any Accounts. There will be errors, the standard "Error: no matches found" lookup field error.

Case 3: user enters a valid Account Name for an existing Account. No typos. Also, for this case assume there is more than one Account with this name. Clicking Save (without first engaging with lookup magnifying glass button) will not associate the donation record with any Accounts. There will be errors visible on the page, SF will return the list of Accounts with that name. The user MUST engage with that field and select (via lookup) the particular Account they wish to associate the donation record with.

There are other cases, but that is how the platform works and those are 3 of the more common cases your users may encounter while using lookup fields and not engaging with the magnifying glass to actually lookup a record.

Also, if you are asking about an auto-complete field... while this is possible, it is custom work (apex controller and visual force page that we could display inline in the page layout). I would discourage you from taking this approach because of the cost and complexity this would add to your SF organization.

Finally, there is no substitute for hands-on experience. I suggest you click around in your org, see for yourself how the lookup fields work on Donation.

Hope this helps. Welcome to SF, its a great platform. Any additional questions, just ask.

Comment: I will be presenting your reply to the full taskforce meeting next week. This is a question we have considered on other fields, as well.